# Upgrade new Google Play Console has effect to app's license key is available in the Play Console

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, in-app

All developers will get the new Google Play Console on November 2, 2020 [enter link description here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/09/all-developers-will-get-new-google-play.html). Is App's license key is available in the Play Console effect? [image]
Please help me to explain this issue. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 8):

On the new Google Play Console select the app, then go to Monetize >> Monetization Setup and you will see the Base64-encoded RSA public key

Comment: Thank you for your support :). My app have been using license key from Google but when check again it changed

Comment: The public key I said in my answer and the one you pasted in your question from the old play console must be the same. This key is used only for verify the purchases signature.

Comment: I'm using Public key signature to in-app purchase (support third-party: Android In-App Billing v3 Library). But I couldn't purchase successful since 01/11/2020. Reason is Public key signature doesn't match. Therefore, I need to know about this issue. Please help me and thank you for support....

Comment: Under no circumstances should the public license and purchase key have changed with the new Google Play Console, unless you have created a new app that will always be created with a new key, the problem has to be elsewhere, Did you change your app code recently?

Answer (score 2):

Many changes has been done  in the new console, so to get BASE64 PUBLIC KEY you follow as in the below picture[image]
select youar app, then monetization setup. then scroll down then copy it.