# Where is Licence Api Key in NEW Google Play Console

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I just can't find app licence API Key in the new Google Play Console. In the help, it says you select your app then click on Development Tools and click on Services & API link. However there is no Development Tools or Services & API links in the new Play Console. Please someone show me where is it?

I need it to activate Unity IAP Services.

Many thanks

Comment: I just don't get it why this question is downvoted. I spent HOURS for the same problem. Still I couldn't find it yet. Where the hell is the Development Tools section???

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770110/7690376

Answer (score 12):

In Play Console, select your app.
Then navigate to Monetize on the left bar.
Under this, you will find Monetization Setup.
Your license key will be there.

[image]